In probability / statistics, if you win 1 time less out of 100 times, what is the disadvantage?
I often hear, if your total "wager" or "bet" \$100, and you lose \$2, then your disadvantage is 2%.
Let's say we play 100 games of Blackjack. If somehow my skill is that instead of winning 50 times and losing 50 times, I lose 1 more time out of this 100 times, then I may say, my disadvantage is 1%.
That's version 1 above.
Let's see for version 2: in this 100 games, let's say I bet \$1 each time, so for that 1 time I should win and get back \$2 total (the wager and the winning total is \$2), I fail that 1 game and therefore cannot get the \$2, so my final result will be: I end up having \$98.  (if it is \$100, then it is break even).
So this version 2 is: I lose \$2 for a total wager of \$100. So the disadvantage is 2%. Or the house advantage is 2%.
So really, is the house advantage version 1: 1%, or is it version 2: 2%?
Or more precisely:

What is the correct way to phrase it? (house advantage or player's disadvantage or a better way to phrase it)
What is the correct way to calculate it?
What is that number: 1% or 2%?


If you wager $$1$ hoping to get back $$2$ and you lose, you have lost $$1$, not $$2$. But if you play $100$ games you cannot win $49$ and lose $50$. You can win $49$ and lose $51$. So that's two more losses than wins.

What actually happens if the house advantage is $1%$ is that on average you win $$99$ for every $$100$ you bet. But the results are random, so if you play $100$ games you may win $50$ or $49$ or $48$ or $51$ or even $55$ games. If you play a much larger number of games your average winnings will tend more closely to the theoretical average. The house plays millions of these games, so maybe the players win about $495000$ and the house wins $505000$ of a million games.

@DavidK I think it is like, if I play 100 million times, is the "house advantage 1% or 2%". What is the correct phrase or what is the number: 1% or 2%

It depends whether your total net loss in those 100 million games was one million dollars or two million dollars.

The house advantage or house edge is typically measured as the the house's expected gain as a proportion of the original bet, so $\frac{51-49}{100}=2\%$ in your example, or $\frac{1}{37} \approx 2.7\%$ in European roulette or $\frac{2}{38} \approx 5.26\%$ in American roulette.
